# Javascript - alert show before click event

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, innerhtml

I wrote this method that flips a card face up `onClick` and then displays an `alert` method. However, for some reason when I click on the card, it stays face down and the `alert` method displays. Then, once I close the alert the card flips over.

How do I have the card flip over and then display the `alert` ?

```
...
newCard.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
...

//method to flip card face up
function flipCard() {

    cardsInPlay.push(this.getAttribute('data-card'));

    if(this.getAttribute('data-card') == 'king'){
        this.innerHTML = '<img src="my_king.png" alt="King of Spades" />';
    } 

    if(this.getAttribute('data-card') == 'queen'){
        this.innerHTML = '<img src="my_queen.png" alt="Queen of Spades" />';            
    }

    if (cardsInPlay.length === 1) {
        alert("Congrats, you flipped a card");
      }

}
```

Comment: Setting the `src` attribute just starts the image "downloading" in the background.  The script will continue on after the download is queued.  The `alert()` function pauses execution of other activities.  Try putting the alert in a short `setTimeout`.  (i.e.  `setTimeout(function() { alert("Congrats, you flipped a card") }, 1);`).  There's other ways to do this too - like adding an event handler to the "onload" for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the correct way is to use promises and callbacks.

https://www.sencha.com/blog/asynchronous-javascript-promises/

That way you can run a function which creates an alert only after some work has been done i.e. you've changed the innerHtml of the current card.

The dodgy way would be doing something like:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    alert("Congrats, you flipped a card");
}, 500);
```